# Reading values from html inputs and inserting them into a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

My html code is as follows. I want to read the values from these inputs and the one select form, create an SQL statement string from it, and insert it into a table. It's a new google map marker btw. I'm not sure how to do this, please help me. I know I can't use php because it's executed beforehand, but I don't know any other way. Thanks in advance.

```
<br> Name <input type="text" id="name"> <br> 
      Adress <br> <input type="text" id="adress"><br> 
      Lat <br><input type="text" id="lat"> <br> 
      Long <br><input type="text" id="long"><br> 
      Type <br> 

      <select style="width: 153px" id="type">
      <option value="vjerski">Vjerski objekti</option>
      <option value="obrazovna">Obrazovne ustanove</option>
      <option value="drzavna">Administracija</option>
      <option value="kulturna">Kulturne ustanove</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Why can't you use PHP? Submit your form, with AJAX if necessary, and use a PHP script to update your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertMarker.php

```
<?php

$db_conn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

$stmt = $db_conn->prepare(
  'INSERT INTO Markers (name, address, lat, long, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
);
$stmt->bind_param('sssss',
  $_POST['name'],
  $_POST['address'],
  $_POST['lat'],
  $_POST['long'],
  $_POST['type']
);
if ( $stmt->execute() ) { echo 'Insert successful.' }
$stmt->close();

?>
```

insertMarker.js

```
function insertMarker() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
      // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('POST', 'insertMarker.php', true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(
    'name='     + document.getElementById('name').value +
    '&address=' + document.getElementById('address').value +
    '&lat='     + document.getElementById('lat').value +
    '&long='    + document.getElementById('long').value +
    '&type='    + document.getElementById('type').value
  );
}
```

insertMarker.html

```
<script src="insertMarker.js"></script>

Name        <input type="text" id="name">   <br> 
Address <br><input type="text" id="address"><br> 
Lat     <br><input type="text" id="lat">    <br> 
Long    <br><input type="text" id="long">   <br> 
Type    <br> 

<select style="width: 153px" id="type">
  <option value="vjerski">Vjerski objekti</option>
  <option value="obrazovna">Obrazovne ustanove</option>
  <option value="drzavna">Administracija</option>
  <option value="kulturna">Kulturne ustanove</option>
</select>

<button onclick="insertMarker()">Insert Marker</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! Before you answered I figured out how to do it, but without AJAX. Now it works flawlessly!